# Local Npm module "autoprefixer-core" not found. Is it installed?

Tags: gruntjs, autoprefixer

Can't really fix it.
I deleted node_modules folder many times. Also tried to replace:
`grunt.loadNpmTasks('/var/www/XXX/public/node_modules/autoprefixer-core');`

=> instead =>

`grunt.loadNpmTasks('autoprefixer-core');`

But nothing helps.
However, fanny moment my code is working:
[image]

I mean **autoprefix-core** is working

But somehow giving error. =(

Please HELP!

Comment: Can you share the relevant parts of the Gruntfile?

Comment: Shure: http://jsfiddle.net/drty70x6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `require` the module yourself inside the `processor`-configuration while passing the object with `browsers` to the module similar to how you would require regular node-modules.

In your Gruntfile, you have this:

```
processors: [
    require('autoprefixer-core')({
      browsers: [
         '> 11%',
         'Chrome >= 10',
         'Explorer >= 6',
         'Opera >= 11',
         'Firefox >= 3.5',
         'Safari >= 4',
         'iOS >= 6'
        ],
        remove: true
     })
]
```

So you don't actually need this as it's not really an task (thus the error):

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('autoprefixer-core');
```

So you can safely remove that line from your config.

Comment: Yeah, i have done as you said, and there is no errors now.
[Image of my result](http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/15/0801/h_1438449056_6929910_2935e4c96a.png)
Thank you very much!